# GL_POINT and GL_LINES - real use?

Tags: opengl, graphics

I've been using OpenGL since some time now for making 3D applications, but I never really understood the use of the GL_POINT and GL_LINES primitive drawing types for 3D games in the production phase.

- (Where) are point and line primitives in OpenGL still used in modern games?

Answer (score 12):

You know, OpenGL is not just for games and there are other kind of programs than just games. Think CAD programs, or map editors, where wireframes are still very usefull.

Comment: +1 for mention that. There are a lot of different use cases where OpenGL can be applied.

Answer (score 7):

`GL_POINTS` are used in games for point sprites (either via the pointsprite functionality or by generating a quad from a point in the geometry shader) both for "sparkle" effects and volumetric clouds.
They are also used in some special algorithms just when, well... *when points are needed*. Such as in building histograms in the geometry shader as by the chapter in one of the later GPU Gems books. Or, for GPU instance culling via transform feedback.

`GL_LINES` have little use in games (mostly useful for CAD or modelling apps). Besides not being needed often, if they are needed, you will normally want lines with a thickness greater than 1, which is not well supported (read as: fast) on all implementations.
In such a case, one usually draws thick lines with triangle strips.

Comment: Note that point sprites have some issues with clipping (they clip as the center of the points, rather than as the quad they are usually rendered with). AMD implements this correctly, according to the OpenGL specification, but NVIDIA does not.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Good comment, they do, very much so. That may in some cases give disturbing popping artefacts (especially with very large sprites), but most of the time you don't notice, luckily. It's probably one reason why they usually won't let you make point sprites larger than 64 pixels too, so the effect is kind of self-limiting (I see no other technical reason why there should be any limit at all). The geometry shader solution luckily does not have any such issues, because it generates 4 points before clipping occurs, and nobody tells you how large that quad may be.

Comment: Who won't let you make point sprites larger than 64 pixels? If you use shader-defined point sprite sizes, both NVIDIA and AMD will let you go up to 2048 or so in size.

Comment: Really? Good to know. Though I recall querying the max size on my (admittedly elderly G92) card 2-3 years or so ago, and the reported value was 64. That was what in fact _made me_ use the geometry shader instead, since I wanted bigger sprites, and without clipping compromises (one of the very few really helpful things you can do with the GS). In retrospective, I believe that was a good move, and by now it's probably silly to plan for people who have no GS support anyway. Someone who still has a _yet older_ card than me probably won't have any fun due to other limitations either way.

Answer (score 4):

Who ever said those primitives were used in modern games?

GL_LINES is critical for wireframe views in 3D modeling tools.

Comment: Sometimes you want to see the wireframe views in games too, but that's usually just in development mode.

Comment: No they are not. Triangles are used for rendering wireframes and rendering is set to the wire frame mode.

Comment: It depends if you are using OpenGL ES or not. In OpenGL ES, there is no polygonMode, and hence only way is to use LINES for wireframes. I think that is what @Alex meant.

Answer (score 3):

> (Where) are point and line primitives in OpenGL still used in modern games?

Where do you want them to be used?

Under standard methods, points can be used to build point sprites, which are 2D flatcards that always face the camera and are of a particular size. They are always square in window-space. Sadly, the OpenGL specification makes using them somewhat dubious, as point sprites are clipped based on the *center* of the point, not the size of the two triangles that are used to render it.

Lines are perfectly reasonable for line drawing. Once upon a time, lines weren't available in consumer hardware, but they have been around for many years now. Of course, antialiased line rendering (GL_LINE_SMOOTH) is another matter.

More importantly is the interaction of these things with geometry shaders. You can convert points into a quad. Or a triangle. Or whatever you want, really. Each "point" is just an execution of the geometry shader. You can have points which contain the position and radius of a sphere, and the geometry shader can output a window-aligned quad that is the appropriate size for the fragment shader to do some raytracing logic on it.

GL_POINTS just means "one vertex per geometry shader". GL_LINES means "two vertices per geometry shader." How you use it is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say for debugging purposes, but that is just from my own perspective.

Some primitives can be used in areas where you don't think they can be applied, such as a particle system.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Pompe de velo about lines being useful for debugging.  They can be useful when debugging AI and collision detection algorithms so that you can visualize the data that is being used by the AI or collision detection.  Some example uses for AI, the lines can be used to show AI paths or path meshes.  Lines can be used to show steering data that the AI is using.  Lines can be used to show what an AI is aiming at.  The data that is shown can be displayed in text form but sometimes it is easier to see it in visual form.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases particles are based on GL_POINT, considering that there can be a huge number of particles on the screen it would be very expensive to use 4 vertices per particle, so GL_POINT solves this problem

GL_LINES good for debugging purposes, wireframe mode can be used in various cases. As mentioned above - in CAD apps, but if you're interesed in gamedev use - it's good for a scene editor.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of collision detection, they come in handy when you want to visualize bounding volumes(boxes,spheres,k-dops) and contact manifolds in wireframe mode. Setting the colour of these primitives based on the status of collisions as well is incredibly useful.